# Run Excel VBA Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean) from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a code in a new workbook to open a few other workbooks with a workbook to update some information, after which they are supposed to run `Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)` upon closing to lock the file. However when I run "Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close", it bypass Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean) and close. I ended up with the updated files which are not locked.

May I know what code should I be using to run BeforeClose? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Workbook_BeforeClose is an event procedure, located in the ThisWorkbook module. You don't use code to run it, it is triggered by the EVENT of closing the workbook either manually or with code. When you close the Active workbook it will look in that workbook's ThisWorkbook module for the Workbook_BeforeClose event handler. I there isn't one there it will just close.

Comment: If the before close event isn't running then maybe you turned `EnableEvents` off?

Comment: I had set the Enable Events to True. It didn't work. I wonder where did I go wrong.